# html fit an image in the middle of the div

Tags: html, css

I have an html like:

```
<div class="image-detail">

    <div class="image-detail-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and its css like:

```
.image-detail{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.image-detail-image{
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vartical-align: center;
}
```

I want the image to be on the center of the div.
It is as expected but only from left and right.
It is always pinned to the top and if the image is small there is gap at bottom.

I want my image to be on the exact middle equal form left right and top down.

Answer (score 0):

Try `object-fit: cover` if you want to put it in the middle no matter what size your div is.

Answer (score 0):

Using table property, you can achieve this .

Just give

```
.image-detail {
  display: table;
}
.image-detail-image {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

This will automatically align the inner `div` exactly the parent's center

```css
.image-detail {
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  display: table;
}
.image-detail-image {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<div class="image-detail">

  <div class="image-detail-image">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" alt="" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working codepen url:
http://codepen.io/SESN/pen/vKKeGg

```
.image-detail{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
}
.image-detail-image{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  vertical-align: center;
  border: 1px solid yellow;
  position: relative;
}
.image-detail-image img { display: block; margin-top: -80px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; margin-left: -80px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.box {
   background-color: black;
  
}
.wrap {
  background-image: url(https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSOcCMn5EeZRPChrpNh3iY60LXlOd8py9vebNofPp0SK0tHoC6x1w);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px dashed #eee;
  margin: auto; 
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
   <div class='wrap'>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:flex` for your expected outcome

```css
.image-detail{
  height: 500px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  text-align: center;
  
}
.image-detail-image{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display:flex;
  background-color:blue;
}
.img{
vertical-align: middle;
  margin:auto;

}
```

```html
<div class="image-detail">

    <div class="image-detail-image">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150" class="img" alt="" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: image won't stretch... its the image holder that will.. let me update it in your style.. @aryan

Comment: I am sorry.. I didn't understand.. @aryan

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Use [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)!**

Depending on which web browsers you need to support, you have two options.

The first (and preferred, modern option) is to use flexbox. Flexbox has full support in most modern browsers: http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

```
.image-detail {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* This vertically aligns the children elements */
  justify-content: center; /* This horizontally aligns them */
}
```

The second option is to use table layout, as @Jinu suggests:

```
.image-detail {
  display: table;
}

.image-detail-image {
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}
```

While this is supported by more browsers, it can lead to some weird consequences (particularly when it comes to how text flows in an element)